# Proving a derivative exists

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, limits, derivatives

If f is differentiable at $x$ then for $\alpha\neq1$ $$f'(x)=\lim_{c\to 0} {{f(x+c)-f(x+\alpha c)}\over{c-\alpha c}}.$$  I am not really sure what it is I need to even show to prove the statement.

Comment: could there be any mistake? since the formula doesn't look good...

Comment: Do you mean $ c\to 0$?

Answer (score 4):

Using just the derivative definition:

$$ \lim_{c\to0}{{f(x+c)-f(x+\alpha c)}\over{c-\alpha c}}=\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\lim_{c\to0}{{f(x+c)-f(x)}\over{c}}-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\lim_{\alpha c\to0}{{f(x+\alpha c)-f(x)}\over{\alpha c}}\\=\frac{f'(x)}{1-\alpha}-\frac{\alpha f'(x)}{1-\alpha}=f'(x)
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try with

$$\frac{f(x+c)-f(x+\alpha c)}{c(1-\alpha)}=\frac{f(x+c)-f(x)+f(x)-f(x+\alpha c)}{c(1-\alpha)}=\\\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\frac{f(x+c)-f(x)}{c}-\frac{1}{1-\alpha}\frac{f(x+\alpha c)-f(x)}{c};$$

Now

$$f(x+\alpha c)-f(x)=f'(x)\alpha c+O(c^2),$$

and so

$$\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x+c)-f(x+\alpha c)}{c(1-\alpha)}=
\frac{1}{1-\alpha}f'(x)-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\lim_{c\rightarrow 0}\frac{f'(x)c+O(c^2)}{c}=\left(\frac{1}{1-\alpha}-\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\right)f'(x)=f'(x).$$

Comment: I meant the limit as $c\rightarrow 0$